# AngularJS - filter returning reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

I was wondering if I do something like this in AngularJS,

```
var myCat = cats.filter(function(comparedCat) {
    if(comparedCat.parentCategory != undefined) {
        return cat.id === comparedCat.parentCategory.id;
    }
});
```

and it returns a list of objects

```
[Object, Object, ...]
```

Are these objects referenced to the the objects in cats? In other words, if I change the subset of cats (returned array of objects), will it change the objects in cats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found out the myCat objects are actually references to objects in cats. That is so cool you can just change the objects returned to be reflected on the original objects.